# Any compiler which takes 'char' as 'unsigned' ?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, char, signed, unsigned-char

Is there any C compiler which takes the default type of char as unsigned unless explicitly mentioned by the user in the file or project settings?

/Kanu_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GCC does. But only when compiling for platforms where an unsigned char is the convention, including ARM linux[*]. When GCC compiles for x86, the default is for char to be signed.

[*] Or at least it has been in the past. For all I know linux has switched to a different default ABI on ARM since.

**Update '2013:** ARM compilers (gcc, clang) for Android NDK default to `unsigned char`. The x86 and MIPS compilers default to `signed char`.

Answer (score 4):

The standard requires that the integer value of all characters required by the standard (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, basic punctuation, etc.) be positive, so any system using an encoding where these characters' values are outside the range of `signed char` **must** have plain `char` be unsigned. I believe this means all EBCDIC systems must have a plain `char` that's unsigned, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: If `CHAR_BIT` > 8 the range of values for `char` is greater than -128..127 or 0..255. So, on an EBCDIC system with CHAR_BIT == 9, a plain `char` can be signed.

Answer (score 2):

There is usually an option to set it as default, but no compiler of my knowledge does that.

Comment: There is. In MSVC you use [`/J` (Default char Type Is unsigned)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx). In GCC you use [`-funsigned-char`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20518559/995714)