# c++ JsonCpp parse string with escaped quotes as array

Tags: c++, arrays, jsoncpp

I've got the following json string:

```
{
    "data" : 
    [
        {
            "cart" : "[{\"name\":\"Test item 1\",\"price\":15,\"quantity\":1,\"sum\":15,\"tax\":\"none\",\"payment_type\":\"advance\",\"item_type\":\"service\"},{\"name\":\"Test item 2\",\"price\":13.01,\"quantity\":2,\"sum\":26.02,\"tax\":\"none\",\"payment_type\":\"part_prepay\",\"item_type\":\"work\"}]",
            "contact" : "noname@google.com",
            "p_id" : "603",
            "sum" : "100.02",
            "tax_system" : "osn"
        }
    ],
    "msg" : null,
    "result" : "success"
}
```

I can parse **cart** as std::string after parsing input json string as stringstream:

```
const std::string ParseJsonData(std::stringstream ssJsonStream)
{
    Json::Value jsonData;
    Json::Value responseData;
    Json::Value responseDataCart;
    Json::CharReaderBuilder jsonReader;
    std::string errs;

    if (Json::parseFromStream(jsonReader, ssJsonStream, &jsonData, &errs)) {
        responseData = jsonData["data"];
        responseDataCart = responseData[0]["cart"];
        return responseDataCart.toStyledString().c_str();
    }
    else
        return "Could not parse HTTP data as JSON";
}
```

Please, tell me, how can i parse **cart** as array with JsonCpp?

Comment: Did you try `responseDataCart = responseData[0]["cart"]["name"];`

Comment: Yes, i tried - it doesn't work.

Comment: Your return statement is wasteful. `toStyledString()` already gives you a `std::string`, which only needs directly returning (which will move it); you're obtaining a C-string out of it then constructing a new string from _that_. It's not the end of the world, but it does require a `strlen` invocation and prohibits moving the data.

Answer (score 2):

The same way you parsed the outer JSON!

You started with a string (well, hidden by a stream) and turned it into JSON.

Now that JSON contains a property that is a string and, itself, contains JSON. The problem is recursive. The fact that the inner string originally came from JSON too can be ignored. Just pretend it's a string you typed in.

So, [you can use JSON::Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47284656/560648) to in turn get the JSON out of that string.

Something like:

```
const std::string responseDataCartStr = responseData[0]["cart"].asString();

Json::Reader reader;
if (!reader.parse(responseDataCartStr, responseDataCart))
   throw std::runtime_error("Parsing nested JSON failed");
```

JsonCpp provides a few ways to parse JSON and it's worth exploring them to find the most appropriate for your use case. The above is just an example.

Ignore the backslashes — the escaping was meaningful within the encapsulating JSON document, but the outermost parse stage should already have taken that into consideration. You'll see if you print `responseDataCartStr` to console that it is a valid JSON document in its own right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Works perfectly with Json::CharReader* reader = jsonReader.newCharReader();

Comment: @MichaelK. Don't forget to `delete` it! I like to use `std::unique_ptr` for the task. I had a memory leak in production where I was doing `auto reader = Json::CharReaderBuilder().newCharReader();` and forgot that it returns a naked pointer :( Needless to say that area of code now has a massive comment warning slapped all over it