# How to check if plain chars are signed or unsigned?

Tags: c++, syntax, char

Apparently there is a possibility that plain `char` can be either signed or unsigned by default. Stroustrup writes:

> It is implementation-defined whether a plain char is considered signed or unsigned. This opens the
>   possibility for some nasty surprises and implementation dependencies.

How do I check whether my chars are signed or unsigned? I might want to convert them to `int` later, and I don't want them to be negative. Should I always use `unsigned char` explicitly?

Comment: @MitchWheat: Yes. Examples I've encountered: Cray T90, Cray SV1, Cray T3E, SGI MIPS IRIX, IBM PowerPC AIX. And any system that uses EBCDIC pretty much has to make plain `char` unsigned.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You should add your list as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728045/any-compiler-which-takes-char-as-unsigned)

Comment: You read the compiler's documentation.

Comment: @PeteBecker: That doesn't necessarily help if you want to check at compile time or run time (though it's usually better to write code that doesn't care whether `char` is signed or unsigned, or to use `signed char` or `unsigned char` if you do care).

Comment: @KeithThompson - yes, obviously, which is why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker: It's obvious to you and me, but might not be to everyone else reading this.

Comment: @KeithThompson - that's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some alternatives:

```
const bool char_is_signed = (char)-1 < 0;

#include <climits>
const bool char_is_signed = CHAR_MIN < 0;
```

And yes, some systems do make plain `char` an unsigned type. Examples I've encountered: Cray T90, Cray SV1, Cray T3E, SGI MIPS IRIX, IBM PowerPC AIX. And any system that uses EBCDIC pretty much has to make plain `char` unsigned so that all basic characters have non-negative values. (And some compilers have an option to control the signedness of `char`, such as gcc's `-fsigned-char` and `-funsigned-char`.)

But `std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed`, as suggested by [Benjamin Lindley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18221312/827263), probably expresses the intent more clearly.

(On the other hand, the methods I suggested can also be applied to C.)

Answer (score 29):

From header `<limits>`

`std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_signed

Answer (score 0):

Using `unsigned char` "always" could give you some interesting surprises, as the majority of C-style functions like `printf`, `fopen`, will use `char`, not `unsigned char`.

edit: Example of "fun" with C-style functions:

```
const unsigned char *cmd = "grep -r blah *.txt";
FILE *pf = popen(cmd, "r");
```

will give errors (in fact, I get one for the `*cmd =` line, and one error for the `popen` line). Using `const char *cmd = ...` will work fine. I picked `popen` because it's a function that isn't trivial to replace with some standard C++ functionality - obviously, `printf` or `fopen` can quite easily be replaced with some `iostream` or `fstream` type functionality, which generally has alternatives that take `unsigned char` as well as `char`.

However, if you are using `>` or `<` on characters that are beyond 127, then you will need to use `unsigned char` (or some other solution, such as casting to `int` and masking the lower 8 bits). It is probably better to try to avoid direct comparisons (in particular when it comes to non-ASCII characters - they are messy anyway, because there are often several variants depending on locale, character encodings, etc). Comparing for equality should work however.

Comment: @chux: Hadn't finished editing... (note to self: Write edit first, then comment to say "see edit")

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want to use a `char` type and you always want it to be unsigned, use `unsigned char`. Note that unlike the other fundamental integer types, `unsigned char` is a different type from `char` -- even on systems where `char` is unsigned. Also, conversion from `char` to `int` [ought to be lossless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030086/671509) so if your result is incorrect, your source `char` value may also be incorrect.

The cleanest way to test whether `char` is unsigned depends on whether you need it to be a preprocessor test and on which version of C++ you are targeting.

To conditionally compile code using a preprocessor test, the value of [`CHAR_MIN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) should work:

```
#include <climits>

#if (CHAR_MIN==0)
// code that relies on char being unsigned
#endif
```

In C++17, I would use [`std::is_signed_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) and [`std::is_unsigned_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned):

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<char>);
// code that relies on char being unsigned
```

If you are writing against C++11 or C++14 you need the slightly more verbose [`std::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_signed) and [`std::is_unsigned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_unsigned):

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(std::is_unsigned<char>::value, "char is signed");
// code that relies on char being unsigned
```

For all revisions of C++, @benjamin-lindley's solution is a good alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You can use preprocessor command:

```
 #define is_type_signed(my_type) (((my_type)-1) < 0)
```

Comment: Why make it a macro rather than, say, a `const bool`?

Comment: @KeithThompson This is more "universal" construction, not for only char types.

Comment: The `numeric_limits<>::is_signed` already covers any sense of "universalness" you are trying to convey.