# Can int be unsigned int by default in some platform?

Tags: c++, c

Can an `int` be unsigned by default like `char` and can someone provide these platform if it exists ?

I mean that `char` can be unsigned or signed depending on platforms.
Is the same thing applicable to `int`, `long`, `short` ?

Comment: Since when is `char` `unsigned` by default?

Comment: Where'd you get that idea ? Oo

Comment: Neither `int` nor `char` are `unsigned` by default. `int` is always signed unless otherwise specified. `char`'s signedness is implementation defined.

Comment: `char` is unsigned in ARM platform. [http://blog.cdleary.com/2012/11/arm-chars-are-unsigned-by-default/](http://blog.cdleary.com/2012/11/arm-chars-are-unsigned-by-default/)

Comment: What did you do to find out yourself? What about the documentation is not clear? You ask a lot of nonsense questions, how about first consulting the standard before asking?

Comment: The standard is 600 pages and I did not find that on google.

Comment: [This](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) is the last C11 draft prior to publication. All in a nice single page. You can search that.

Comment: @Sabrina: Yes, every developer *should* dig into their handy reference manuals and language standards **before** going online to ask questions.  I have no less than 5 language reference manuals on my desk *right now* (C, C++, Perl, Python, and SQL).  I have a Unix programming reference, a Linux desktop reference, a UML guide, a copy of Design Patterns, and both the C and C++ online standards bookmarked.  If, after checking a reference, you don't understand something, then *by all means* ask a question here, but *at least* do you own research first.  No less is asked of the rest of us.

Comment: Heck I up-voted. At least it's something we can suggest as a duplicate for any future question of the sort.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "`int` is always signed unless otherwise specified." has an exception. With bit-fields, a plain `int` may be treated as `unsigned int`.  With bit-fields, better to use `signed int` and `unsigned int` rather than `int`.

Comment: It is curious that a question formed well enough to elicit good (and high scoring) answers from people of high rep on this site can at the same time be so easily down-voted by others for such reasons as "look it up yourself".  Questions can be judged, at least in part, by the quality of the responses they have attracted.  This question, although terse, addresses subtleties that many new programmers would benefit from.  (+1)

Comment: @ryyker no problem I get used to that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ARM implementations usually use `unsigned` char by default [Any compiler which takes 'char' as 'unsigned' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728045/995714), [Does anyone know why "char" is unsigned on ARM/gcc?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18269886), [Why unsigned types are more efficient in arm cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3093669/995714), [ARM chars are unsigned by default](https://web.archive.org/web/20121202022150/https://blog.cdleary.com/2012/11/arm-chars-are-unsigned-by-default/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [C11 standard section "5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types "](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1):

> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions
>   suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for
>   CHAR_BIT and MB_LEN_MAX, the following shall be replaced by
>   expressions that have the same type as would an expression that is an
>   object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. Their implementation-defined values **shall be equal or
>   greater in magnitude (absolute value)** to those shown, **with the same**
>   **sign**.
>   ...........................
>   minimum value for an object of type `int`
>   `INT_MIN                                -32767`
>   maximum value for an object of type `int`
>   `INT_MAX                                +32767`

So, as you can see the limits of `int` have to be at least the ones specified (absolute values) with the same signs.

Comment: You skipped very important part `Their implementation-defined values`

Comment: @Sabrina No I haven't. It says their implementation defined values are limited by the emphasized text. So no matter of implementation they must have a range [-32767, 32767]. So their implementation can only increase this range.

Comment: I have seen INT_MIN defined as -32768 in most places.  Is yours actually -32767?

Comment: @ryyker There is a linked standard document draft. `-32767` is good for the possible sign-and-magnitude representation.

Comment: You might want to mention that reading the entire of 5.2.4.2.1 makes it clear that `char` is a special case, and all other integer types are required to be signed unless `unsigned` is used.

Answer (score 11):

No, `int` is always signed. Unlike `char`, which may behave as a `signed char` or `unsigned char` depending on the platform, `int` is always a synonym for `signed int`, regardless of the platform, in both C and C++.

> Reference: C99, 6.2.5.4:
>
> There are five standard signed integer types, designated as `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`.
>
> Reference: C++11, 3.9.1.2:
>
> There are five standard signed integer types : `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, and `long long int`.

Comment: Why there is no `short` ?

Comment: "`int` is always signed." deserves a note about _bit-fields_: "if the actual type specifier used is `int` or a typedef-name defined as `int`, then it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field is signed or unsigned."

Comment: @chux Thank you very much for the comment! You are absolutely right, bit fields are governed by a separate set of rules. I wasn't sure if I wanted to open this can of worms in the context of this question, because it sounds like OP wants to find out a very specific thing unrelated to bit fields.

Answer (score 7):

`char` is peculiar: there are three flavors, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, and `char`. A plain `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation, but in C++ it's a different type from the other two. All the other integer types have just two flavors, signed and unsigned; you can say `unsigned int`, `signed int`, and just plain `int`, but plain `int` is signed, and it's just a different name for `signed int`. In the C++ standard, that's clause 3.9.1, [basic.fundamental].