# C++ - Characters with value greater than 127 get negative value

Tags: c++, char

in my C++ program, I have the following line:

```
text += (char)value;
```

The `value` is an ASCII value and whenever this value is greater than 127, the corresponding character (added to the `text`) **has a negative value**. Why ? And how can I prevent that ?
Note: `text` is just a string

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725665/char-value-got-negative-after-adding-it-to-a-string) on StackOverflow. A related thread but no solutions were provided there.

Comment: It's *implementation defined* (i.e. it's up to the compiler) if `char` is signed or unsigned. And as on almost all system `char` is an 8-bit type then a signed `char` will have a range from `-128` to `127`.

Comment: On another note, if you ever feel the need to do a C-style cast (like `(char)` in `(char)value`) then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. If the compiler gives you a warning about it, then it probably have a good reason, and the right solution is almost never to do a cast to silence the compiler.

Comment: There are no ASCII characters with values greater than 127.

Comment: `static_cast<unsigned char>(value)`

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: [ES.48: Avoid casts](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es48-avoid-casts)  [ES.49: If you must use a cast, use a named cast](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es49-if-you-must-use-a-cast-use-a-named-cast)

Comment: @nurettin: thanks. it worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 'char' signed by default in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c)

Comment: [Why don't the C or C++ standards explicitly define char as signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15533115/995714), [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714)

Answer (score 0):

`char` is by default signed, and its size is one byte (8 bits). A byte allows representing 256 different values. When said byte is signed, it can represent values ranging from -128 and 127. If you want it to represent numbers between 0-255, you should cast your variable `value` to `unisgned char`.
`text += (unsiged char)value;` would work fine.

Anyways, there is not a char represented by an ascii value greater than 127.

Edit: as mentioned in a comment, char is not signed by default. However, it is signed when using g++ and the vs compiler on windows.

Comment: "`char` is by default signed" is *wrong*. It's *implementation defined* (i.e. up to the compiler) if `char` is signed or unsigned. Even the same compiler can have different configurations depending on target systems.

Comment: `However, it is signed when using g++` this is **wrong**. `char` is usually unsigned by default on ARM implementations even with gcc: [Why unsigned types are more efficient in arm cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3093669/995714), [Does anyone know why "char" is unsigned on ARM/gcc?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18269886), [Any compiler which takes 'char' as 'unsigned' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3728045/995714)

Comment: @phuclv please note that I only mentioned g++ on windows.