# Why don't the C or C++ standards explicitly define char as signed or unsigned?

Tags: c++, c, types, compiler-construction, standards

```
int main()
{
    char c = 0xff;
    bool b = 0xff == c;
    // Under most C/C++ compilers' default options, b is FALSE!!!
}
```

Neither the C or C++ standard specify char as signed or unsigned, it is implementation-defined.

Why does the C/C++ standard not explicitly define char as signed or unsigned for avoiding dangerous misuses like the above code?

Comment: There is no “C/C++ standard” standard. But the question stands for both standards.

Comment: Generally standards leave things explicitly undefined to be flexible for implementations to do whatever they think is appropriate (or fast) for their platform.

Comment: @teppic: Incorrect. `int` is always equivalent to `signed int`; `unsigned int` is a distinct type.

Comment: The reasoning is precisely in the statement in your question: "...it is implementation-defined". Specifically in **C++11 § 3.9.1p1**, "In any particular implementation, a plain char object can take on either the same values as a signed char or an unsigned char; which one is implementation-defined." In other words, they are very specific about it being implementation-dependent whether it is signed or unsigned, but it must be consistent on that implementation. It is specified this way to the advantages, and behest, of the implementors.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I'm sure I read otherwise recently -- I'd always thought the same myself.

Comment: `// b is always FALSE!!!` <- No, it will be true on implementations where `char` is unsigned.

Comment: @teppic: I guarantee that `int` and `signed int` are names for the same type in both C and C++. If you read otherwise, you read something that was incorrect.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, but that doesn't explain *why* it's implementation-defined.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I wasn't contradicting you. I found the reference - I was skim reading this: *it is implementation-deﬁned whether the speciﬁer int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int.* -- but missed the bit before that says this is for bitfields.

Comment: I don't think we can know why the standards committee decided a certain thing. Any answer is just guessing, or giving our own reasons why we would have decided that way.

Comment: @teppic: Yes, that's right, it's for bit fields only, I forgot about that. Which means it rarely makes sense to define a bit field as `int`. For that matter, defining a bit field as `signed int` is explicit, but rarely useful; most bit fields are unsigned.

Comment: @Sancho: Not at all. Many of the committee's decisions are well documented.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah, I didn't know that. Thank you. Are these searchable? Where at?

Comment: @KeithThompson Why it *would be* implementation-dependent as opposed to standard-mandated as one or the other, is what I think you're saying. Good question. And regarding `signed int` vs `int`, the former isn't even specified as one of the five mandated integer types in C++11. Indeed only "signed char" is specifically called out. The others, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int” are "signed" by definition as being the "signed integer types". (3.9.1p2). Now I need to scour the standard for "signed int" yuck. =P

Comment: The C Programming Language says about `char` that it must be large enough to store any member of the execution character set as an integer, while also being non negative.

Comment: @WhozCraig: `signed int` is simply another name for `int`. Look up "type specifiers" in the C++ standard. On the other hand, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, and `char` are three distinct types; `char` has the same representation as one of the other two.

Comment: @KeithThompson Found it, 7.1.6.2. Thanks for the pointer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Historical reasons, mostly.

Expressions of type `char` are promoted to `int` in most contexts (because a lot of CPUs don't have 8-bit arithmetic operations). On some systems, sign extension is the most efficient way to do this, which argues for making plain `char` signed.

On the other hand, the EBCDIC character set has basic characters with the high-order bit set (i.e., characters with values of 128 or greater); on EBCDIC platforms, `char` pretty much has to be unsigned.

The [ANSI C Rationale](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/title.html) (for the 1989 standard) doesn't have a lot to say on the subject; section 3.1.2.5 says:

> Three types of char are specified: `signed`, plain, and `unsigned`.  A
>   plain `char` may be represented as either signed or unsigned, depending
>   upon the implementation, as in prior practice.  The type `signed char`
>   was introduced to make available a one-byte signed integer type on
>   those systems which implement plain char as unsigned.  For reasons of
>   symmetry, the keyword `signed` is allowed as part of the type name of
>   other integral types.

Going back even further, an early version of the [C Reference Manual](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf) from 1975 says:

> A `char` object may be used anywhere an `int` may be. In all cases the
>   `char` is converted to an `int` by propagating its sign through the upper
>   8 bits of the resultant integer. This is consistent with the two’s
>   complement representation used for both characters and integers.
>   (However, the sign-propagation feature disappears in other
>   implementations.)

This description is more implementation-specific than what we see in later documents, but it does acknowledge that `char` may be either signed or unsigned. On the "other implementations" on which "the sign-propagation disappears", the promotion of a `char` object to `int` would have zero-extended the 8-bit representation, essentially treating it as an 8-bit unsigned quantity. (The language didn't yet have the `signed` or `unsigned` keyword.)

C's immediate predecessor was a language called B. B was a typeless language, so the question of `char` being signed or unsigned did not apply. For more information about the early history of C, see the late Dennis Ritchie's <strike>[home page](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/index.html)</strike>, now [moved here](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/).

As for what's happening in your code (applying modern C rules):

```
char c = 0xff;
bool b = 0xff == c;
```

If plain `char` is unsigned, then the initialization of `c` sets it to `(char)0xff`, which compares equal to `0xff` in the second line.  But if plain `char` is signed, then `0xff` (an expression of type `int`) is converted to `char` -- but since `0xff` exceeds CHAR_MAX (assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`), the result is *implementation-defined*. In most implementations, the result is `-1`. In the comparison `0xff == c`, both operands are converted to `int`, making it equivalent to `0xff == -1`, or `255 == -1`, which is of course false.

Another important thing to note is that `unsigned char`, `signed char`, and (plain) `char` are three distinct types.  `char` has the same representation as *either* `unsigned char` *or* `signed char`; it's implementation-defined which one it is. (On the other hand, `signed int` and `int` are two names for the same type; `unsigned int` is a distinct type. (Except that, just to add to the frivolity, it's implementation-defined whether a bit field declared as plain `int` is signed or unsigned.))

Yes, it's all a bit of a mess, and I'm sure it would have be defined differently if C were being designed from scratch today. But each revision of the C language has had to avoid breaking (too much) existing code, and to a lesser extent existing implementations.

Comment: Side Bar: AS/400 and OS/390 both take extreme advantage of the bit layout of their respective EBCDIC characters sets for radix trees implemented in the underlying hardware. Hard to get much more implementation-defined than those platforms.

Comment: How does this apply to `wchar_t`?

Comment: @ipc: It doesn't apply; `wchar_t` is a distinct type. In C, `wchar_t` is a typedef defined in `<stddef.h>`. It's an integer type, but the standard doesn't specify its signedness. In C++, it's a distinct predefined integral type with the same characteristics as one of the other integral types.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Why? `char[32|64]_t` are unsigned, having `wchar_t` implementation-defined signed  does not make sense to me.

Comment: @ipc: You mean `char[16|32]_t`. Both are recent additions to both C (as typedefs in `<uchar.h>` and C++ (as fundamental types). I agree it makes sense for character types in general to be unsigned, but when `wchar_t` was added to the language that probably wasn't as clear as it is now. `char` has implementation-defined signedness for the historical reasons I've tried to explain in my answer. When `wchar_t` was defined, the same reasons probably applied. (I don't think it was even clear that `wchar_t` would necessarily be Unicode.)

Comment: The Unicode was only a work in progress in 1989 & 1990. http://www.unicode.org/history/versionone.html There were (and are) other multibyte (as well as variable byte length) encodings in the wild at the time. Given that time it would not have made since to say wchar_t was meant to be Unicode ahead of knowing if the standardization effort would work.

Comment: ... And not providing a type to handle the existing implementations of multi-byte character sets.

Answer (score 0):

`char` at first is meant to store characters, so whether it's signed or unsigned is not important. What really matters is how to perform maths on `char` efficiently. So depend on the system, the compiler will choose what's most appropriate

> Prior to ARMv4, ARM had no native support for loading halfwords and signed bytes. To load a signed byte you had to LDRB then sign extend the value (LSL it up then ASR it back down). This is painful so char is unsigned by default.
>
> [why unsigned types are more efficent in arm cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532932/995714)

In fact a lot of ARM compilers still use `unsigned char` by default, because even if you can load a byte with sign extension on modern ARM ISAs, that instruction is still less flexible than the zero extension version

- [is char signed or unsigned by default on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20576300/995714)
- [`char` is `unsigned` by default on Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054959/995714)

And most modern compilers also allow you to change char's signness instead of using the default setting

Comment: So-called character types have two uses in C: to store characters, or to access raw storage.  The Standard actually focuses more on the second usage, since the Standard requires implementations to honor special guarantees about character types which are often essential when accessing raw storage, but uselessly impede optimization when working with data representing actual characters.