# Why char data type have negative range?

Tags: c

As far as integers, floats, double are concerned there -ve range exists because number can be -ve as well as +ve but:

- Why char too have a -ve range from -128  as char is character ( i mean how can it be -ve )?

Can anybody help me to understand logic behind this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is 'char' signed by default in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c)

Comment: Please note that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are distinct types. `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on the platform.

Comment: Sometimes people use `char` for calculations (not for processing of characters). Many years ago it was necessary to economy memory :) So programmers had to use `char` for processing of small integer values.

Answer (score -1):

this is historic. 7 bits are all you needed for US-ASCII Characters plus control characters (CR, LF, RET, BS, ...), so you had one bit left for other use (EOF f.e.). To represent this, char was designed as signed.