# ANSI character handling by C and C#

Tags: c#, c, casting, character-encoding

I have a character '¿'. If I cast it with integer in C, result is -61 and same casting in C#, result is 191. Can someone explain me the reason.

```
C Code
char c = '¿';
int I = (int)c;
Result I = -62


C# Code
char c = '¿';
int I = (int)c;
Result I = 191
```

Comment: C# does not use ANSI but Unicode (UTF-16).

Comment: C# `char` is equivalent to C `wchar_t`, not `char`.  `char` on your compiler couldn't contain the value 191 even if it wanted to (allowable range  -128 through +127)

Comment: Note that "C code" is implementation dependent behavior - there is no requirement for `char` to be signed. See [Why is 'char' signed by default in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c)

Comment: unsigned char can contains 0 ... 255.  and -61 is a signed version of unsigned 191.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how singed/unsigned numbers are represented and converted.

It looks like C compiler's default in your case use `signed byte` as underlying type for `char` (since you are note explicitly specifying `unsigend char` compiler's default is used, See - [Why is 'char' signed by default in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c) ).

So 191 (0xBF) as signed byte means negative number (most significant bit is 1) - `-65`.

If you'd use `unsigned char` value would stay positive as you expect.

If your compiler would you wider type for `char` (i.e. `short`) that 191 would stay as positive 191 irrespective of whether or not `char` is signed or not.

In C# where it always unsigned - see MSDN [char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx):

> Type: char 
>    Range: U+0000 to U+FFFF

So 191 will always convert to to `int` as you expect.