# char overflow at ~125+

Tags: c++, char

Long program short: I am reading binary file byte by byte and after each read byte I output this byte but not as a character( as I declared a variable `char c` and store the values in that ) but as `int`. When I come to binary values around 125 above I get values negative values.

For example when I read `hex 89` = `dec 137` and I output this char as `int`, I get value `-119`.

Another example: I read `hex 83` = `dec 131` and I output this char as `int`, I get value `-125`.

I read this file by bytes:

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile . open( srcName, ios::binary | ios::in );

char c;

while( inFile . get( c ) ){
  inFile . get( c );
  cout << (int) c << endl;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `char` is *signed* on your system.

Comment: Assuming a signed char, everything will be in the range of -128 to 127

Comment: hmm but char is of 1 byte size

Comment: ahh and what now :D this function doesnt allow `unsigned char`

Comment: Try casting it to an `unsigned char` first? And please don't use C-style cast, learn about [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

Comment: you can always use if((int)c < 0) c += 256;

Comment: @Rtoip Assuming that `c` is still a char (i.e. 1 byte), what would that achieve?

Comment: That is because `signed char` has the sign bit. Thus, `signed char` supports less numbers, but also allows them to be negative, but `unsigned char` supports more numbers, but they must be positive or 0. The `signed` ness of a char is implementation defined.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried that and compiler sends me error like: `main.cpp:106:46: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::get(char)’
    inFile2      . get( static_cast<char>(c1) );`

Comment: @stackptr this method is not taking `unsigned char` as a parameter

Comment: Do they still teach two's complement math in high school, or college-level CS curriculum? Apparently not.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Right, I didn't think this through. But if one stored the result in an `int`, this would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you wanted to ask why do you see negative values when you expected positive.

First, you should not read data from a file into a `char`. In C and C++, functions reading a character from files or standard input (`getchar()`, `fgetc()`, `ifstream::get()` and so on) return an `int`. The reason is the need to detect the end of file (or input). The function needs to return some value that can be checked and is different from any possible byte (char) value - in binary file, you can encounter a byte with any value.

And second, `char` may and may not be `signed` in C++ (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c) for further details). Your `char` seems to be a `signed char`. That means it can represent numbers in the (-128,127) range, and it interprets byte values over 127 as negative numbers. That is why you see them as negative (C++ will convert `(char) -119` into `(int) -119`). If you want positive values, declare your `c` as `unsigned char` (or `unsigned int`).

Comment: ifstream::get() needs argument of type `char`

Comment: You can use the `get()` signature, which returns an `int`.

Then your code would be:
`int c;

while ((c = inFile.get()) != EOF) {
  cout << c << endl;
}`

An `int` should work, even when `signed`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to say is that `char` is not guaranteed to be `signed` or `unsigned` by the standard - this is system and implementation specific. Then, you shouldn't use `char` for such a task 'cause even if it works fine (which is not your case) it might break when you use a different compiler or a different system.

Second thing to say is that you should not use C-style casts, use `static_cast` instead. C-style casts are not safe and there is a lot of complexity under their simple syntax.

To fix your problem you could use `unsigned char` instead of `char`. If for some reason this is not possible - you could try casting to `unsigned char` before (implicitly) casting to `unsigned int` like this:

```
unsigned int val = static_cast<unsigned char>(a);
```

Comment: compiler prints error.. ifstream::get() needs `char` arguments

Comment: well, "If for some reason this is not possible - you could try casting to `unsigned char` before (implicitly) casting to `unsigned int` like this: ...". Simply `get` the numbers into a `char` and then use my code above to convert this into an `unsigned int`. It should work.