# Why is std::string implemented as basic_string of `char` and not `unsigned char`

Tags: c++, string

`typedef basic_string<char> string;`

All the `std::string` facilities in the standard library are using `char`. Why is that? Although all the characters of the ASCII table (128) fit into the range of a `char` (-128 to 127), many other character encodings are using 8-bits for representation.

What is the advantage of having 'negative' values in a string of chars?

Comment: just a side note: `char` can be signed or unsigned, it isnt specified by c++

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c

Comment: the question isnt a dupe, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17097575/4117728) has a quote that more or less answers also your question

Comment: `char` can be either signed or unsigned, and might contain more than 8 bits, and ASCII isn't a requirement either. Whatever works best on the system you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals are of type `const char*`, so it would require a O(n) conversion when doing `std::string("fooo")`.