# Is it Normal For Chars to be Between -128 and 127?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, char, bit

To find out the range of integer values for a standard 8-bit char, I ran the following code:

```
int counter = 0;

for (int i = -300; i <= 300; i++)
{
    char c = static_cast<char> (i);

    int num = static_cast<int> (c);

    if (num == i)
    {
        counter ++;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Bad:  " << i << "\n";
    }
}

cout << "\n" << counter;
```

I ended up seeing a value of 256 for counter, which makes sense.  However, on the list of "Bad" numbers (i.e., numbers that chars don't store), I found that the greatest Bad negative number was -129, while the smallest Bad positive number was 128.

From this test, it seems like chars only store integer values from -128 to 127.  Is this conclusion correct, or am I missing something?  Because I always figured chars stored integer values from 0 to 255.

Comment: Can be either, it's implementation defined. `char` can even have more than eight bits, but not fewer.

Comment: `char` is `signed char` in your implementation, so there are negative and positive values. Use `unsigned char` and they'll start at `0`.

Comment: There exist `signed char`, `unsigned char` and `char`. It is implementation defined, if char is signed or unsigned.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Oops, my dupe was for C, not C++. What's the rule for C++?

Comment: It's the same for C++ @Barmar. All the basic integer stuff is simply inherited from C for compatibility, and it's not going to change either.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although implementation defined, for the most part - yes it is normal as your implementation defines `char` as a `signed char`. You can use the `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX` macros to print out the minimum and maximum values of type `char`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::cout << CHAR_MIN << '\n';
    std::cout << CHAR_MAX << '\n';
}
```

Or using the [std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<char>::min()) << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(std::numeric_limits<char>::max()) << '\n';
}
```

As for the 0..255 range that is the `unsigned char` type. Min value is `0` and max should be `255`. It can be printed out using:

```
std::cout << UCHAR_MAX;
```

Whether the type is signed or not can be checked via:

```
std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed;
```

Excerpt from the [char type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) reference:

> `char` - type for character representation which can be most
>   efficiently processed on the target system (has the same
>   representation and alignment as **either** `signed char` or `unsigned
>   char`, but is always a distinct type).