# Unsigned char* instead of char*

Tags: c, strlen

Why most c functions with string in param usually has definition `char*` and not `unsigned char*`? According to my understanding `unsigned char*` is more generic.
And how to deal in situations when I have `unsigned char*` and need to pass to `char*` in correct way?

For example is it good style to call function in sample below?

```
unsigned char* a=...
strlen((char*)a);
```

Comment: The question is too general IMHO. And anyway - _"According to my understanding unsigned char* is more generic"_ - what do you mean by that ?

Comment: If you need to cast something, in contrast to an alternative method where you don't need to, I bet on the one without casting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the C or C++ standards explicitly define char as signed or unsigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533115/why-dont-the-c-or-c-standards-explicitly-define-char-as-signed-or-unsigned)

Comment: The general statement isn't quite true. The only time *unsigned char* is required is when dealing with `<ctype.h>` functions. Otherwise, whether you have a pointer to `char` or `unsigned char` is largely irrelevant for functions in `<string.h>` as long as what you have is a C-string, i.e. a nul-terminated string. Certain libraries, like `libssl`, etc.. make use of the unsigned variants in special circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The standard states that :

> An object declared as type char is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative. If any other character is stored in a char object, the resulting value is implementation-defined but shall be within the range of values that can be represented in that type.

`char` is guaranteed to be able to represent all characters as a positive number.

Moreover :

> The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called
> the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char.

It is implementation defined if `char` is signed or not.

The type `char` is, thus, the type defined to be the best fit to store characters for the implementation. There are no need to cast it to an `unsigned char`.

Also, you say that *"According to my understanding `unsigned char*` is more generic."*. You may be referring to the fact that the sign of `char` is implementation defined, and using `unsigned` makes it more predictable across implementations. While this would be true when using it for arithmetic, the standard ensures that when using it for string and characters, the value is never negative, making it predictable across all implementations.

Comment: Re “the standard ensures that when using it for string and characters, the value is never negative”: This is not true. As the passage you quoted says, the standard requires this only for characters in the basic execution character set. A C implementation may have additional characters with negative values. Further, the standard does not even require the `char` type be able to distinguish all 256 possible values of eight bits. So `unsigned char` is objectively superior for portability.

Answer (score 0):

> Why most c functions with string in param usually has definition `char*` and not `unsigned char*`?

Because `char` is the (original) data type intended for character data.  Denotionally, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are for small *numbers*.  Strings and string functions were conceived as serving needs related to character data, so they are defined in terms of type `char`.  It's the semantically consistent thing to do.

> According to my understanding `unsigned char*` is more generic.

I don't know how you got that idea.  `char` and `unsigned char` (and `signed char`) are distinct types.  C does not have any kind of subtyping, but `char` could be considered more generic than `unsigned char` in that as far as the spec is concerned, `char` defines only the size of objects, not their signedness.  Or in that it somehow caters to the platform's native treatment and interpretation of character data, regardless of what exactly that may be.  On the other hand, I don't see any case for considering `unsigned char` more generic than `char`.

C does have a generic pointer type, in the sense that there are implicit conversions in both directions between that type and all other object-pointer types.  That type is spelled `void *`, but ancient, pre-`void` C code generally used `char *` where modern code would use `void *`.

> And how to deal in situations when I have unsigned char* and need to pass to char* in correct way?

If you are talking specifically about string functions, then you should define your own strings as sequences of `char`, not of `unsigned char`, and thereby avoid the issue.

But if you have null-terminated byte sequences on which you want to use the string functions, even though the sequences are not inherently character in nature, then it should pretty much just work.  You will need to cast the pointers, like you show in your example, but whether type `char` is signed or unsigned, it is valid to access `unsigned char` data as if it were `char` data (and *vice versa*), and these types do not have any trap representations that could interfere.

Do take care, however, for arbitrary binary data generally are not null terminated and cannot easily be converted to null-terminated form. Appending a null byte usually cannot be relied upon to help, because it is rarely safe to assume that there aren't any internal null bytes.  Thus, the string functions are usually inappropriate for such data.

Or if you have functions that use `char *` as a generic pointer type, and you are unwilling or unable to convert them to use `void *` instead, and whatever your `unsigned char *` points to is suitable for those functions to operate on, then just do the pointer conversion on your input pointer, and get on with it.  You're already assuming that the pointed to thing is acceptable.