# Regarding type safety when storing an unsigned char value in char variable

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, language-lawyer, type-safety

I have a `char` array holding several characters. I want to compare one of these characters with an `unsigned char` variable. For example:

```
char myarr = { 20, 14, 5, 6, 42 };
const unsigned char foobar = 133;

myarr[2] = foobar;

if(myarr[2] == foobar){
    printf("You win a shmoo!\n");
}
```

Is this comparison *type safe*?

I know from the **C99** standard that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three different types (**section 6.2.5** paragraph 14).

- Nevertheless, can I safely convert between `unsigned char` and `char`, and back, without losing precision and without risking undefined (or implementation-defined) behavior?

---

In **section 6.2.5** paragraph 15:

> The implementation shall define **`char`** to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either **`signed char`** or **`unsigned char`**.

In **section 6.3.1.3** paragraph 3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

I'm afraid that if `char` is defined as a `signed char`, then `myarr[2] = foobar` could result in an *implementation-defined* value that will not be converted correctly back to the original `unsigned char` value; for example, an implementation may always result in the value `42` regardless of the `unsigned` value involved.

- Does this mean that it is not safe to store an `unsigned` value in a `signed` variable of the same type?

Also what is an *implementation-defined signal*; does this mean an implementation could simply end the program in this case?

---

In **section 6.3.1.1** paragraph 1:

> -- The rank of **`long long int`** shall be greater than the rank of **`long int`**, which shall be greater than the rank of **`int`**, which shall be greater than the rank of **`short int`**, which shall be greater than the rank of **`signed char`**.
>
> -- The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
>   signed integer type, if any.

In **section 6.2.5** paragraph 8:

> For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank
>   (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a
>   subrange of the values of the other type.

In **section 6.3.1** paragraph 2:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an **`int`**; otherwise, it is converted to an **`unsigned int`**.

In **section 6.3.1.8** paragraph 1:

> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

The range of `char` is guaranteed to be the same range as that of `signed char` or `unsigned char`, which are both subranges of `int` and `unsigned int` respectively as a result of their smaller integer conversion rank.

Since, integer promotions rules dictate that `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` be promoted to at least `int` before being evaluated, does this mean that `char` could maintain its "signedness" throughout the comparision?

For example:

```
signed char foo = -1;
unsigned char bar = 255;

if(foo == bar){
    printf("same\n");
}
```

- Does `foo == bar` evaluate to a false value, even if `-1` is equivalent to `255` when an explicit `(unsigned char)` cast is used?

---

**UPDATE**:

In **section J.3.5** paragraph 1 regarding which cases result in implementation-defined values and behavior:

> -- The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type
>   when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (6.3.1.3).

- Does this mean that not even an explicit conversion is safe?

For example, could the following code result in implementation-defined behavior since `char` could be defined as a *signed integer type*:

```
char blah = (char)255;
```

Comment: read this: [Deep C: Integer Promotion](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original post is rather broad and consists of many specific questions of which I should have given each its own page. However, I address and answer each question here so future visitors can grok the answers more easily.

---

## Answer 1

**Question**:

> - Is this comparison type safe?

The comparison between `myarr[2]` and `foobar` in this particular case is safe since both variables hold unsigned values. In general, however, this is not true.

For example, suppose an implementation defines `char` to have the same behavior as `signed char`, and `int` is able to represent all values representable by `unsigned char` and `signed char`.

```
char foo = -25;
unsigned char bar = foo;

if(foo == bar){
    printf("This line of text will not be printed.\n");
}
```

Although `bar` is set equal to `foo`, and the C99 standard guarantees that there is no loss of precision when converting from `signed char` to `unsigned char` (*see **Answer 2***), the `foo == bar` conditional expression will evaluate *false*.

This is due to the nature of *integer promotion* as required by **section 6.3.1** paragraph 2 of the C99 standard:

> If an **`int`** can represent all values of the original type, the value is converted to an **`int`**; otherwise, it is converted to an **`unsigned int`**.

Since in this implementation `int` can represent all values of both `signed char` and `unsigned char`, the values of both `foo` and `bar` are converted to type `int` before being evaluated. Thus the resulting conditional expression is `-25 == 231` which evaluates to *false*.

---

## Answer 2

**Question**:

> - Nevertheless, can I safely convert between `unsigned char` and `char`, and back, without losing precision and without risking undefined (or implementation-defined) behavior?

You can safely convert from `char` to `unsigned char` without losing precision (nor width nor information), but converting in the other direction -- `unsigned char` to `char` -- can lead to *implementation-defined behavior*.

The C99 standard makes certain guarantees which enable us to convert safely from `char` to `unsigned char`.

In **section 6.2.5** paragraph 15:

> The implementation shall define **`char`** to have the same range,
>   representation, and behavior as either **`signed char`** or **`unsigned char`**.

Here, we are guaranteed that `char` will have the same *range*, *representation*, and *behavior* as `signed char` or `unsigned char`. If the implementation chooses the `unsigned char` option, then the conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` is essentially that of `unsigned char` to `unsigned char` -- thus no width nor information is lost and there are no issues.

The conversion for the `signed char` option is not as intuitive, but is implicitly guaranteed to preserve precision.

In **section 6.2.5** paragraph 6:

> For each of the signed integer types, there is a corresponding (but different) unsigned
>   integer type (designated with the keyword **`unsigned`**) that uses the same amount of
>   storage (including sign information) and has the same alignment requirements.

In **6.2.6.1** paragraph 3:

> Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type **`unsigned char`** shall be
>   represented using a pure binary notation.

In **section 6.2.6.2** paragraph 2:

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three
>   groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits; there shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as
>   the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are
>   *M* value bits in the signed type and *N* in the unsigned type, then *M* `<=` *N*).

1. First, `signed char` is guaranteed to occupy the same amount of storage as an `unsigned char`, as are all signed integers in respect to their unsigned counterparts.
2. Second, `unsigned char` is guaranteed to have a *pure binary* representation (i.e. no padding bits and no sign bit).
3. `signed char` is required to have *exactly one* sign bit, and no more than the same number of value bits as `unsigned char`.

Given these three facts, we can prove via [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) that  the `signed char` type has at most *one less* than the number of value bits as the `unsigned char` type. Similarly, `signed char` can safely be converted to `unsigned char` with not only no loss of *precision*, but no loss of *width* or information as well:

- `unsigned char` has storage size of *`N`* bits.

  - `signed char` must have the same storage size of *N* bits.
- `unsigned char` has no padding or sign bits and therefore has *`N`* value bits
- `signed char` can have at most *`N`* non-padding bits, and must allocate *exactly one* bit as the sign bit.

  - `signed char` can have at most *`N-1`* value bits and *exactly one* sign bit

All `signed char` bits therefore match up one-to-one to the respective `unsigned char` value bits; in other words, for any given `signed char` value, there is a unique `unsigned char` representation.

```
/* binary representation prefix: 0b */
(signed char)(-25)   = 0b11100111
(unsigned char)(231) = 0b11100111
```

Unfortunately, converting from `unsigned char` to `char` can lead to *implementation-defined behavior*. For example, if `char` is defined by the implementation to behave as `signed char`, then an `unsigned char` variable may hold a value that is outside the range of values representable by a `signed char`. In such cases, either the result is *implementation-defined* or an *implementation-defined signal* is raised.

In **section 6.3.1.3** paragraph 3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

---

## Answer 3

**Question**:

> - Does this mean that it is not safe to store an `unsigned` value in a `signed` variable of the same type?

Trying to convert an `unsigned` type value to a `signed` type value can result in implementation-defined behavior if the `unsigned` type value cannot be represented in the new `signed` type.

```
unsigned foo = UINT_MAX;
signed bar = foo;    /* possible implementation-defined behavior */
```

In **section 6.3.1.3** paragraph 3:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

An implementation-defined *result* would be any value returned within the range of values representable by the new `signed` type. An implementation could theoretically return the same value consistently (e.g. `42`) for these cases and thus loss information occurs -- i.e. there is no guarantee that converting from `unsigned` to `signed` to back to `unsigned` will result in the same original `unsigned` value.

An implementation-defined *signal* is that which conforms to the rules laid out in *section 7.14* of the C99 standard; an implementation is permitted to define additional conforming signals which are not explicitly enumerated by the C99 standard.

In this particular case, an implementation could theoretically raise the `SIGTERM` signal which requests the termination of the program. Thus, attempting to convert an `unsigned` type value to `signed` type could result in a program termination.

---

## Answer 4

**Question**:

> - Does `foo == bar` evaluate to a false value, even if `-1` is equivalent to `255` when an explicit (`unsigned char`) cast is used?

Consider the following code:

```
signed char foo = -1;
unsigned char bar = 255;

if((unsigned char)foo == bar){
    printf("same\n");
}
```

Although `signed char` and `unsigned char` values are promoted to at least `int` before the evaluation of a conditional expression, the explicit `unsigned char` cast will convert the `signed char` value to `unsigned char` before the *integer promotions* occur. Furthermore, converting to an `unsigned` value is well-defined in the C99 standard and does not lead to *implementation-defined behavior*.

In **section 6.3.1.3** paragraph 2:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type

This the conditional expression essentially becomes `255 = 255` which evaluates to *true*.
until the value is in the range of the new type.

---

## Answer 5

**Questions**:

> - Does this mean that not even an explicit conversion is safe?

In general, an explicit cast to `char` for a value outside the range of values representable by `signed char` can lead to *implementation-defined* behavior (*see **Answer 3***). A conversion need not be implicit for **section 6.3.1.3** paragraph 3 of the C99 standard to apply.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed references. In short, unsigned byte must be used for binary data manipulation. I just wonder what a char is good for if it cannot represent all the values of an unsigned char. How is fgets supposed to handle binary data, if char happens to be signed and to be able to store strictly less than 256 (CHAR_BIT == 8 assumed) different values? I guess that it is not specified and that char is thus good only for US-ASCII in (0..127). Any opinions or historical hints? Why is it not specified whether a char is signed or not, like for other arithmetic types?

Comment: @Loic It seems that the decision to leave char's signedness up to the implementation was largely a historical decision to allow optimization on certain machine architectures which handle `signed char` to `int` promotions differently. See the [why is char's sign-ness not defined in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914242/why-is-chars-sign-ness-not-defined-in-c) question here on Stack Overflow for more information.

Answer (score 1):

"does this mean that `char` could maintain its 'signedness' throughout the comparison?" yes; `-1` as a `signed char` will be promoted to a `signed int`, which will retain its `-1` value. As for the `unsigned char`, it will also keep its `255` value when being promoted, so yes, the comparison will be false. If you want it to evaluate to true, you will need an explicit cast.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Actually **section 6.2.5** paragraph 9 seems to imply that this behavior will always occur.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sorry, I'm having trouble following. Are you suggesting that integer promotion could result in a trap value?

Comment: @VilhelmGray yes correct your both types are same so bit pattern never get change and not a implementation dependent thing. I was wrong. that section useful when comparison b/w int/char. discard my comments here.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how the memory for the char's are stored, in an unsigned char, all 8 bits are used to represent the value of the char while a signed char uses only 7 bits for the number and the 8'th bit to represent the sign.

For an example, lets take a simpler 3 bit value (I will call this new value type tinychar):

```
bits    unsigned  signed
000     0         0
001     1         1
010     2         2
011     3         3
100     4         -4
101     5         -3
110     6         -2
111     7         -1
```

By looking at this chart, you can see the difference in value between a signed and an unsigned tinychar based on how the bits are arranged.  Up until you start getting into the negative range, the values are identical for both types.  However, once you reach the point where the left-most bit changes to 1, the value suddenly becomes a negative for the signed.  The way this works is if you reach the maximum positive value (3) and then add one more you end up with the maximum negative value (-4) and if you subtract one from 0 you will underflow and cause the signed tinychar to become -1 while an unsigned tinychar would become 7.  You can also see the equivalence (==) between an unsigned 7 and the signed -1 tinychar because the bits are the same (111) for both.

Now if you expand this to have a total of 8 bits, you should see similar results.

Comment: While this honestly is a nice explanation of two's complement, this answer is a bit unrelated to my question. I know that `signed` and `unsigned` can have overlapping representations in memory, but I'm more concerned about whether C99 standard makes explicit guarantees on the casting of `unsigned char` and `char`.

Comment: @VilhelmGray: So far as I can tell, the number of conforming production implementations of C99 or C11 that use anything other than two's-complement math stands at zero and is unlikely to change.  The closest almost-conforming implementation I know of that doesn't use two's-complement lacks an unsigned type longer than 36 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and it doesn't compare `(signed char)-1` and `(unsigned char)255` the same.
You should convert signed char into unsigned char first, because it doesn't use the MSB sign bit in operations.

I have bad experience with using signed char type for buffer operations. Things like your problem then happen. Then be sure you have turned on all warnings during compilation and try to fix them.